# Multiple EVE-NG instances behind a Ubuntu Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I'm trying to setup multiple instances of EVE-NG community edition behind an apache reverse proxy server.  No need for internet or ssl, just http is fine, but if it's a must, I can add https.  I get a blank page when I add "/anything" to the Proxypass/ProxypassReverse, but the page loads fine from "/".  Any help will be much appreciated.  Below is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com


    # this machine acting as apache reverse proxy
    ServerName 10.10.0.198:80
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    RewriteEngine       On

    ProxyPass /netgear http://netgear/
    ProxyPassReverse /netgear http://netgear:/

    # EVE NG host 1
    ProxyPass / http://10.10.0.251/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.0.251/

    # EVE NG host 2
    ProxyPass / http://10.10.0.252/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.0.252/

    # EVE NG host 3
    ProxyPass / http://10.10.0.253/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.0.253/
```

Comment: Are you sure of this : `ProxyPassReverse /netgear http://netgear:/` ? Why put `:` ?

Comment: Furthermore, according to my knowledge, `# EVE NG host 2` and `# EVE NG host 3` parts are useless as `# EVE NG host 1` override them (the order is important). You need to create 2 others virtual host for that.